# Make PHP and JAVASCRIPT work together.

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple php if statement that checks for an error return on a form submit basically.

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <div class="alert alert-error" id="error"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

And I have this script that I want to put into this php so when the php is true the login box or `account-container` will shake.

```
$("#account-container").addClass("animated shake");
```

I tried echoing the script inside the php but all that was give me `echo ;` displayed on the page when the if was true.

Comment: why don't you just add the script block directly in that php code?

Comment: Do you mean place `$("account-container)....` after `<div class="alert alert-error)....`? If so, I tried this and nothing happened.

Comment: maybe something like `if ($("#error")) $("#account-container").addClass("animated shake");` somewhere in your php script (the onload event handler perhaps)?

Comment: @Eineki `if ($("#error").length)`

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't know jquery and assumed that return false (silly) and not an empty collection when the selector miss the element

Comment: I placed the code after the `div class...` and nothing happens.

Comment: `<script>if ($("#error").length) $("#account-container").addClass("animated shake");</script>` that is what I added with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this script, I'm not at ease with jquery and you would have to adapt the code:

```
$(function(){
    if ($("#error").length !== 0) {
         $("#account-container").addClass("animated shake");
    }
});
```

Place it in the header as javascript source or embedded in a script tag

The `$().load` hook the containing handler to the onload event in the page*
The function simply check if there is an element in the page with id error and
add the class to the #account-container element if is the case.

- I won't use $().ready() as the dom can still be partially rendered

References:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/  Says to use .load() function for onload event and
alert that a `<body onload="something">` tag is not compatible with the jquery event management

http://api.jquery.com/load/ Can be useful

Comment: Change `$().load(fucntion(){` to `$( document ).ready(function(){` and place it outside of the php if statement and this answer works.

Comment: Stackoverflow junkies: Should I accept this answer even though I had to do the above or should I make my own answer and approve it in 2 days?

Comment: Ok, didn't want to break any common practice rules :)

Comment: @Eineki You're welcome. I usually don't fix other people's code in answers, as I believe it's a bit intrusive. But since you said you don't know jQuery very well, this time I did it. In this case, it should really be `$(document).ready` (or the equivalent shorthand that I used), not `.load`.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are using Jquery for the javascript shake, you should call the javascript routine when the page is ready to load

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>shake demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  #toggle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click anywhere to shake the box.</p>
<div id="toggle">This is rendered by PHP</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#toggle" ).effect( "shake" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that the whole page is rendered by PHP, and the script will work when the document render is ready.

Comment: This is making the shake effect happen on click basically, which is not what I am wanting at all. I need the shake event to happen on event. Sorry.

Comment: Also, the shake function is being called by a css stylesheet `http://daneden.me/animate/` so the add class name is correct.